# Primary_Owner_AUM is not aggregating financial accounts (Salesforce Financial Services Cloud)

Tags: fields, financialforce

The Primary Owner AUM field does not seem to be aggregating financial accounts at the household or individual level. Is this not supposed to be a rollup? If not, is there a field that provides this functionality out of the box (there should be!)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Rollups" rules functionality built into FSC, and run the rollups you want to use. Note: aggregation is a manual process and must be automated using an Apex class if you wish the field to update automatically with the balance (Annoying? Extremely.)